# numpy.power(x1, x2) is not equal to x1**x2

Tags: python, numpy

I've found something peculiar regarding the `power` function from numpy which is inconsistent with what I thought was the general python-type-handling philosophy.

I had assumed that the output of `numpy.power(x1, x2)` is numerically equal to `x1**x2`, however this turns out not to be the case in case `x2 < 0`. As shown below:

```
In [320]: 2**-8
Out[320]: 0.00390625

In [321]: np.power(2, -8)
Out[321]: 0

In [322]: np.power(2., -8)
Out[322]: 0.00390625
```

While the philosophy is taught to be that the python interpreter changes type when necessary (e.g., `1/3 = 0.333`, instead of `0`), the numpy.power function appears to have escaped this philosophical change...

Or is there a reason why this is done the way it is done...???

kind regards

Comment: What's your NumPy version? On `1.12.1` the second one raises Value error.

Comment: ah check.. I've got 1.11.1.... I'll update it, I prefer obviously the exception over an unexpected answer.

thanks

Comment: Every base numpy integer type has a maximum size, and an array of them won't change dtype to grow when an value goes out of bounds.  numpy has different goals in mind.